# Given a key id, update few properties of one of the objects inside the array. How?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the following array:

```
let tblUsers = [
    { id: 101, user: 'user1', password: 'password1', created: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', modified: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', status: 'Active', firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Marley' }, 
    { id: 102, user: 'user2', password: 'password2', created: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', modified: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', status: 'Inactive', firstName: 'Bill', lastName: 'Murray' }, 
    { id: 103, user: 'user3', password: 'password3', created: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', modified: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', status: 'Active', firstName: 'Jeniffer', lastName: 'Connelly' }, 
];
```

For id 102, how would I update some or all key-values for that object inside the array?

Comment: If mutation is OK, use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find by ID and store a reference to it, and then update away.

Comment: Omg... `find()` and reference. Of course. Spent so much time thinking of a title for the question that I missed the little things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the first object in the array which matches the condition, which, in our case, is whether the `id` property is equal to `103`:

```js
let tblUsers = [
    { id: 101, user: 'user1', password: 'password1', created: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', modified: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', status: 'Active', firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Marley' }, 
    { id: 102, user: 'user2', password: 'password2', created: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', modified: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', status: 'Inactive', firstName: 'Bill', lastName: 'Murray' }, 
    { id: 103, user: 'user3', password: 'password3', created: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', modified: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', status: 'Active', firstName: 'Jeniffer', lastName: 'Connelly' }, 
];


const user3 = tblUsers.find(user => user.id == 103)

user3.status = 'Inactive';

console.log(tblUsers)
```

Comment: So clean. Thank you Spectric. You were first to answer.

Comment: @suchislife No problem. You should accept the answer which helps you the most.

Comment: Yup. You've answered so fast there's a timer still going. 2 mins to go.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let tblUsers = [
    { id: 101, user: 'user1', password: 'password1', created: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', modified: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', status: 'Active', firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Marley' }, 
    { id: 102, user: 'user2', password: 'password2', created: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', modified: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', status: 'Inactive', firstName: 'Bill', lastName: 'Murray' }, 
    { id: 103, user: 'user3', password: 'password3', created: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', modified: '2021-01-01 23:59:59', status: 'Active', firstName: 'Jeniffer', lastName: 'Connelly' }, 
];

const objectToChange = tblUsers.find((obj) => obj.id === 102);
objectToChange.user = 'user111';

console.log(tblUsers);
```